# Python Kernel died, restarting

Tags: python-3.x, crash, anaconda, scatter-plot, spyder

I am using Anaconda 3 and Python 3 on Windows 10 16 GB RAM 64 bit

```
C:\DATASET>conda --version
conda 4.3.4
C:\DATASET>python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)\

Spyder version 2.3.8
windows 10
```

No matter where I give this command of about 32000 dataset it makes the kernel die and in python prompt direct the python program dies in windows.

```
1.import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
2.#Basic relationship between x and y axis this is not residual plot
3.plt.scatter(X_train,Y_train,color=['red','blue'])
4.#Residual plots are here
5.plt.scatter(lm.predict(X_train),(lm.predict(X_train) -      
Y_train),s=40,alpha=0.5,color=['red','blue'])
6.plt.scatter(lm.predict(X_test),(lm.predict(X_test) - Y_test),s=40,color=
['red','blue'])
```

In the Code above no matter where I run it in spyder or direct on python prompt the line 3 graph is plotted with no problem but the line 5. fails with the crash.
Since it is crashing at plt matplotlib so I thought doing following should resolve:

```
conda update matplotlib
```

But this did not help at all there is still the problem on the 5 th line it crashes. I commented 5th and then ran the 6th line same crash problem.

Below is a conda list installed packages:

```
C:DATASET>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
alabaster                 0.7.7                    py35_0
anaconda                  4.0.0               np110py35_0
anaconda-client           1.4.0                    py35_0
anaconda-navigator        1.1.0                    py35_0
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1
astropy                   1.1.2               np110py35_0
babel                     2.2.0                    py35_0
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py35_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_1
blaze                     0.9.1                    py35_0
bokeh                     0.11.1                   py35_0
boto                      2.39.0                   py35_0
bottleneck                1.0.0               np110py35_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_2  [vc14]
cffi                      1.5.2                    py35_0
chest                     0.2.3                    py35_0
cloudpickle               0.1.1                    py35_0
clyent                    1.2.1                    py35_0
colorama                  0.3.7                    py35_0
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py35_0
conda                     4.3.4                    py35_0
conda-build               1.20.0                   py35_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0
conda-manager             0.3.1                    py35_0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py35_1
cryptography              1.4                      py35_0
curl                      7.45.0                   vc14_1  [vc14]
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
cython                    0.23.4                   py35_0
cytoolz                   0.7.5                    py35_0
dask                      0.8.1                    py35_0
datashape                 0.5.1                    py35_0
decorator                 4.0.9                    py35_0
dill                      0.2.4                    py35_0
docutils                  0.12                     py35_1
dynd-python               0.7.2                    py35_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_0
flask                     0.10.1                   py35_1
flask-cors                2.1.2                    py35_0
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_0  [vc14]
gevent                    1.1.0                    py35_0
greenlet                  0.4.9                    py35_0
h5py                      2.5.0               np110py35_4
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_4  [vc14]
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_0
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
idna                      2.0                      py35_0
ipykernel                 4.3.1                    py35_0
ipython                   4.1.2                    py35_1
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py35_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0
jdcal                     1.2                      py35_0
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_0
jpeg                      8d                       vc14_0  [vc14]
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_2
jupyter_client            4.2.2                    py35_0
jupyter_console           4.1.1                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.1.0                    py35_0
libdynd                   0.7.2                         0
libpng                    1.6.27                   vc14_0  [vc14]
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_1  [vc14]
llvmlite                  0.9.0                    py35_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_0
lxml                      3.6.0                    py35_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_1
matplotlib                1.5.3               np111p  y35_1
menuinst                  1.3.2                    py35_0
mistune                   0.7.2                    py35_0
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_2
mpmath                    0.19                     py35_0
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0
nbconvert                 4.1.0                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py35_0
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0
nltk                      3.2                      py35_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_0
notebook                  4.1.0                    py35_2
numba                     0.24.0              np110py35_0
numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py35_2
numpy                     1.11.3                   py35_0
odo                       0.4.2                    py35_0
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2g                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.18.0              np110py35_0
partd                     0.3.2                    py35_1
path.py                   8.1.2                    py35_1
patsy                     0.4.0               np110py35_0
pep8                      1.7.0                    py35_0
pickleshare               0.5                      py35_0
pillow                    3.1.1                    py35_0
pip                       8.1.1                    py35_1
pip                       9.0.1                     <pip>
ply                       3.8                      py35_0
psutil                    4.1.0                    py35_0
py                        1.4.31                   py35_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_0
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_3
pyflakes                  1.1.0                    py35_0
pygments                  2.1.1                    py35_0
pymongo                   3.4.0                     <pip>
pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py35_0
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_1
pyreadline                2.1                      py35_0
pytables                  3.2.2               np110py35_2
pytest                    2.8.5                    py35_0
python                    3.5.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.5.1                    py35_0
pytz                      2016.2                   py35_0
pywin32                   220                      py35_1
pyyaml                    3.11                     py35_3
pyzmq                     15.2.0                   py35_0
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_0  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.3.2                    py35_0
qtconsole                 4.2.0                    py35_1
qtpy                      1.0                      py35_0
requests                  2.12.4                   py35_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py35_1
scikit-image              0.12.3              np110py35_0
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py35_1
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_1
seaborn                   0.7.1                     <pip>
setuptools                20.3                     py35_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_0
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py35_0
sphinx                    1.3.5                    py35_0
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.1.9                    py35_0
spyder                    2.3.8                    py35_1
sqlalchemy                1.0.12                   py35_0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py35_0
sympy                     1.0                      py35_0
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
toolz                     0.7.4                    py35_0
tornado                   4.3                      py35_0
traitlets                 4.2.1                    py35_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0
vboxapi                   1.0                       <pip>
vs2015_runtime            14.00.23026.0                 0
werkzeug                  0.11.4                   py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
xlrd                      0.9.4                    py35_0
xlsxwriter                0.8.4                    py35_0
xlwings                   0.7.0                    py35_0
xlwt                      1.0.0                    py35_0
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_2  [vc14]
```

The above packages are they giving any hint of conflict or any other problem?
Please give any suggestion as I am stuck here.

Updated Experiment of above:

```
xt=lm.predict(X_train)
xytrain=xt-Y_train
**plt.scatter(xt,xytrain)**

**Kernel died, restarting**

**Kernel died, restarting**
```

I thought instead of making the scatter function heavy maybe computing beforehand and then putting the variables into the function could help but no the kernel crashed as you can see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case solution was reinstalation of CUDA Development Tools and update of MS Visual Studio Community 2015.